# Least mean square method for multiple functions at once in python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares

I have 2 formulas that describes the behaviour in 2 perpendicular axes. Also I have data from FEM simulation. The goal is to use least mean square method to get parameters Rr, Lr and cm.

[image]

I wanted to use scipy.curve_fit unfortunately it accepts only single function as an input. In this case i would need it to accept 2 functions as an input.

I did something in excel where arguments are inserted by hand to prove that it can/can not be perfectly fitted. They cant be but i would like to get "best" fit.

[image]

Any idea how it can be solved besides hard coding the last mean square method by hand to calculate deviances and find min?
Thank you so much for help.

Comment: You need to describe your problem better. What do you mean that you need it to accept two functions? How do you assess the goodness of fit for the two things together?

Comment: You can put the relative importance of the functions in a hyperparamter `lambda`, then use `func1 + lambda * func2`

Comment: please add the images into the post rather than as links to prevent link rot

Comment: This problem seems similar to the problem of "parameters identification of complex impedance model" in electronics especially in electrochemistry. There is a vaste literature on the subject. : Impedance spectroscopy (EIS). For more specific help, please joint to your question an example of data (numerical, not graph).

Answer (score 1):

If not using packages like [`lmfit`](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/examples/example_fit_multi_datasets.html) or similar, fitting curves with shared parameters will always require to write some sort of wrapper. Personally I'd write a residual function and use [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html), but if one insists to use `curve_fit`, this would be a possible wrapper:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def f1( x, c, L, R):
    a = c**2 * x / ( R**2 + (x * L )**2 )
    return a * x * L

def f2( x, c, L, R):
    a = c**2 * x / ( R**2 + (x * L )**2 )
    return a * R

def falt( x, c, L, R, n=-1):
    """
    by construction x is the doubled x-list, 0 <= nn / l < 1 
    and >= 1/2 is the second part
    """
    if isinstance( x, ( list, tuple, np.ndarray ) ):
        ### curve_fit sends array
        l = len( x )
        out = [ falt( xx, c, L, R, n=( nn / l ) ) for nn, xx in enumerate( x ) ]
    else:
        if n < 0.5:
            out = f1( x, c, L, R)
        else:
            out = f2( x, c, L, R)
    return out
## some data
c0=1.2
L0=0.3
R0= 0.45
size = 99
xl = np.linspace( 0, 10, size )
y1l = f1( xl , c0, L0, R0 ) + ( 2 * np.random.random( size=size ) - 1 ) * 0.1
y2l = f2( xl , c0, L0, R0 ) + ( 2 * np.random.random( size=size ) - 1 ) * 0.1


sol, err = curve_fit(
    falt,
    np.append( xl, xl ),
    np.append( y1l, y2l )
)
print( sol )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the relative importance of the functions in a hyperparamter `lambda`, then use `func1 + lambda * func2`.

With code:

```
importance_of_func1_relative_to_func2 = 1

def objective(args1, args2):
    return func1(args1) * importance_of_func1_relative_to_func2 + func2(args2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the goal (not sure of that!), I think that what you might want to do is have a single function that evaluates your 2 values for Fperp and Fpara and then *concatenates* them.   You wrote those as both being multiplied by `|z|` (maybe `abs(zhat)`?) -- I cannot tell if that should be a common scaling factor, a fitting variable, or some other array of values...

Anyway, I might suggest a function like

```
def f_model(omega, cm, rr, lr, zhat):
    ll    = lr * omega
    scale = abs(zhat) * cm**2 / (rr**2 + ll**2)
    fpara = scale * ll * omega
    fperp = scale * rr * omega 
    return np.concatenate((fpara, fperp))
```

Then you would want to arrange the data that you model with this function to also be the concatenation of the data corresponding to `fpara` and `fperp`.

That concatenation would effectively fit `Fpara` and `Fperp` together, weighting them evenly in the fit.